# how to resize images via nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

everybody. tell me how to solve this puzzle. Nginx passes the URL type https://example.com/thumbs/_default_upload_bucket/236/280/5804.jpeg If this image does not exist, nginx should retrieve and resize the original image: replace "thumbs/" and size "236/280/" URL will be https://example.com/_default_upload_bucket/5804.jpeg

If I understand correctly to do this through the module ngx_http_image_filter_module.

How to do this through nginx. Thanks.

Comment: This could be a starting point: 
https://www.nginx.com/blog/responsive-images-without-headaches-nginx-plus/
and here another interesting article:
https://stumbles.id.au/nginx-dynamic-image-resizing-with-caching.html

Comment: i will check that article, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after research, i created a configuration that needed to me.

```
location ~* /thumbs/(.*)/(\d+)/(\d+)/(.*)$ {
    set $bucket $1;
    set $width $2;
    set $height $3;
    set $filename $4;
    try_files /$1/$2/$3/$4 @images;
    root /var/www/html/tmp/image-thumbnails;
    expires 2w;
    access_log off;
}


location @images {
    root /var/www/html/assets/;
    rewrite ^.*$ /$bucket/$filename break;
    image_filter_buffer 50M;
    image_filter resize $width $height;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nginx provides the image_filter module for the dynamic image resizing. This Nginx configuration will allow for requests such as **http://server.com/images/880/dis.jpg** - this image will be resized to 880 pixels wide and compressed using the quality value of 90. Requests asking for images larger than 10 megabytes (before resizing) will be resized.

```
    server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name server.com;

  location ~ "^/images/(?<width>\d+)/(?<image>.+)$" {
    alias /srv/www/images/$image;
    image_filter resize $width -;
    image_filter_jpeg_quality 90;
    image_filter_buffer 10M;
  }
}
```